# AS2 - cross domain loading xml

Tags: xml, cross-domain, actionscript-2

Is there any alternative to cross domain xml loading than with XML()?

I wrote a script in AS2 that basically loads a remote xml feed and parses it, it all worked great in the cs5.5 editor however when I deployed it on a server, it all of a sudden stopped working.

Is there any other http get function in AS2 that I can use and then parse the results with an xml parser or something to get around this? I don't really want to have to proxy to a php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, cross-domain is not allowed in flash.

Comment: so there is no other way around querying a remote server? I find this kind of pointless especailly with rss feeds so available.

Comment: You can find more information about cross-domain policy here  : http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html